# eth0 not installed on CentOS

Tags: linux, networking, centos

How would I go about installing **eth0** on CentOS? When I do `ifconfig -a`, **eth0** is not there. Here is the output of `ip link`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
3: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue
    link/void
```

Comment: What do you mean by installng eth0? Is CentOS not seeing your network card? What is the output of the `ip link` command? Also, what CentOS version are you using?

Comment: What card is it?

Comment: What do you mean by what card?

Comment: @user68973, are you using a virtual private server (VPS)?

Comment: Yes, I am. It's Linux.

Comment: For some reason, I cannot propose an edit, but you should seriously reformat this post (use code block formatting, for example). In its current form, it's actually rather difficult to read.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm fairly new here. I'll edit it to the best of my abilitys.

Comment: @user68973, please accept my edit.

Comment: I accepted it, now can you try to help me with getting eth0 on my server?

Comment: We need to know what card you're using and if it's drivers are in use, run "lspci -v" and scroll up/down until you find "Ethernet Controller" which will be there somewhere assuming Linux is detecting your card at all.

Once you find this, copy the entire section and paste it to the OP you have here to give us info on what card you're using and what drivers you need if they are not in use. (If your card is properly being used, near the bottom of the section it will say "Kernel drivers in use:")

Comment: Which version of CentOS? 5 or 6?

Answer (score 7):

Network interfaces can have different names on Linux depending on their type (wired Ethernet, Wi-Fi, PPP, SLIP, etc.), PCI slot, initialization order, etc. For example if a computer has a single Ethernet card, its name would be **eth0**<sup>*</sup>.

In your case, there's a *virtual* private server without an Ethernet network card in it, not even an emulated one. Nevertheless you have a network card named **venet0**. You can rename it with:

```
ip link set venet0 name eth0
```

If the interface is in use the command will fail, so you might need to bring it down (`ip link set venet0 down`), but this will probably disconnect you from the server.

If you're willing to take the *risk*, you could run in the background a script that brings the interface down, renames it, then brings it up. First get the settings for **venet0** and the routing table:

```
[root@server ~]# ip addr show dev venet0
2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/void
    inet 127.0.0.1/32 scope host venet0
    inet X.Y.Z.T/32 brd X.Y.Z.T scope global venet0:0
[root@server ~]# ip ro
192.0.2.0/24 dev venet0  scope host
169.254.0.0/16 dev venet0  scope link  metric 1002
default dev venet0  scope link
```

Then create a script (`rename-to-eth0.sh`) similar to this:

```
#!/bin/sh
### Rename
ip link set venet0 down        # Bring interface down
ip link set venet0 name eth0   # Rename interface    
ip link set eth0 up            # Bring interface up
### Restore
# Restore interface settings. Adapt accordingly!!!
ip addr add 127.0.0.1/32 scope host dev eth0
ip addr add X.Y.Z.T/32 brd X.Y.Z.T scope global label eth0:0 dev eth0
# Restore routing table. Adapt accordingly!!!
ip ro add 192.0.2.0/24 dev venet0 scope host
ip ro add 169.254.0.0/16 dev venet0 scope link metric 1002
ip ro add default dev eth0
```

Now run the script with [**nohup**](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/nohup-invocation.html) i.e. `nohup ./rename-to-eth0.sh` or inside **screen**, **tmux**, etc. If it fails, you'll probably have to restart the server.

<sub><sup>*</sup> Things will change as the ["Predictable Network Interface Names"](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) proposal is implemented, although this does not apply to CentOS6 or earlier. Take note that according to this proposal an integrated Ethernet card might be named **em1**.</sub>

Comment: I tried that it didn't work for the script I have, I need eth0.

Comment: @user68973, I've updated my answer with an (ugly) way to do the rename.

Comment: +1 for explaining why there isn't an eth0.  Any script that has `eth0` hardcoded into it sounds like a really badly done piece of work, BTW.

Comment: Thank you! I agree regarding the script. And if it's really a script then it should be easier to adapt it (with a plain search&replace perhaps) than mess with this renaming.

Answer (score 2):

If your use of eth0 can simply be modified to refer to the network interface by the name "venet0" wherever you would use "eth0" then you can just do that.

If, however, you have to have the name eth0, you can do something like

```
sudo ip link set dev venet0 alias eth0
```

The "sudo" prefix allows you to execute commands as "root" user. If you're already running as root, you can leave this off. In fact, probably you should try it without and if there are no errors then you win!

Comment: I'd recommend using `su -l -c` instead of `sudo` because not every computer has **sudo**.

Comment: here is the output of that command
Error: either "dev" is duplicate, or "alias" is a garbage.