# How do I add enable eth0 on CentOS8?

Tags: linux, centos, networking

I'm trying to learn Linux and DevOps.

I've been going through the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wvf0mBNGjXY

I'm currently stuck at the 1:10:00 of the video.

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.10/24 dev eth0
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

```
cannot find device "eth0"
```

Can anyone walk me through how to fix this issue?

I tried this link and unfortunately it didn't work: [eth0 not installed on CentOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138811/eth0-not-installed-on-centos)

When I do ifconfig, I’m only seeing 3 options enp0s3, lo, virbr0.

Thanks!

Comment: Just substitute `enp0s3` for `eth0` as you follow the tutorial. Different Linux systems are set up to have different naming schemes for the interfaces. So you just need to adapt the tutorial for your system.

Answer (score 1):

Run `ip l` or `ifconfig` to find out what network interfaces you've got. `eth0` can still be used (some reconfiguration is required) but has been deprecated in favour of the naming scheme which is based on hardware parameters and is a lot more predictable and precise.

In your case `enp0s3` is what you're looking for - it represents your LAN card thus you do not need to enable or add `eth0`.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

To see the network devices, just run the command:

```
ip addr
```

You can then use the following to set the IP address:

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.10/24 dev $device_name
```